# Rails3 - Turn off email logging

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have log_level that has a default of 'info'. But I see emails that are sent being logged. How can I turn this off only for emails?

This is inside my config/application.rb:

```
# See everything in the log (default is :info)
# config.log_level = :debug
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put this in your `environment.rb` file, emails should not be logged:

```
ActionMailer::Base.logger = nil
```